# strange behaviour when closing stdout

Tags: c, sockets, stdout

I have a program. In this program I have a http session with oher equipment. and in the program I have many `printf`. when I close the `stdout` with `fclose(stdout)` I remark that messages printed by the `printf` are send to the http session (messages included in the http packets).

I m wondering about this strange behvior and I m wondering How to avoid that behavior ? I mean how to avoid the redirect of the printed messages to the http session ?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `printf` after `fclose(stdout)` invokes undefined behavior. Don't do it. If you just need to inhibit `stdout`, open /dev/null and `dup2` it onto fd #1.

Comment: the stdout could be closed by an accident. For example close of the ssh session which I use to launch my application. The ssh session could be closed accidentelly if another user have changed the ip address. what I have to do in this case?

Comment: No it can't be. Disconnected and closed are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you're closing the file descriptor used by stdout, and the next file descriptor created (a socket, in this case) is ending up at the file descriptor traditionally used by it (FD 1).

Don't close stdout. If you need to make it go away, replace it with a file descriptor pointed to `/dev/null`, e.g:

```
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
```

Comment: `freopen` is not required to reuse the same fd number so it may result in serious problems if some code is writing to stdour by fd rather than by stdio.

Comment: The documentation states that "The primary use of the freopen() function is to change the file associated with a standard  text  stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout)." So I'd be very surprised if it didn't keep the same FD. (In practice, it definitely does.)

Comment: the stdout could be closed by an accident. For example close of the ssh session which I use to launch my application. The ssh session could be closed accidentelly if another user have changed the ip address. what I have to do in this case?

Comment: Nothing -- the situations you've described will not cause stdout to be closed. Unless you call `close()`, or something that calls `close()`, in your application, stdout will stay open. (It may just be open to nothing.)